# How do I sync a Slack workspace from mobile to desktop?

Tags: slack

I was added to a Slack workspace by a coworker. I must've accepted something on the mobile app because I have access to the workspace there. Somehow, the desktop app never reflected this change and shows no sign of knowing about the workspace. I attempted to solve this problem by inviting myself to the workspace from the mobile app and accepting the invite link on the desktop app. I now have access to the workspace on the desktop app, but no direct messages have been carried over. (My desktop is Debian and mobile is iOS, if that makes any difference.)

I can't find any discussion about this on the Slack website or through a DuckDuckGo search... Does anyone know how to sync Slack from mobile to desktop? I will greatly appreciate any suggestions or direction. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a workaround (it is not ideal so I'm still searching for a better solution):

From the channel(s) I wanted to sync, on the mobile app, I added myself and now I have access to those channels on the desktop app. Unfortunately, I show up as two members with the same name...

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible and despite the fact that this question was raised as soon people had two devices, Slack never agreed to address it.

On desktop I have no less than 15 workspaces.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround that just worked for me was signing out of the desktop app and signing again. That allowed me see all the workspaces I was already in.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I was struggling just now with the opposite problem: there was a Slack workspace that I could see in my computer but not in my mobile app. I write here how I solved it in case someone faces the same problem in the future.

In my case, it turned out that the problem was that I was using different email addresses for the different workspaces (either my professional or personal email), and I had pending to verify one of the addresses.

To solve it I:

1. Opened the **Home menu** by either sweeping right of tapping on the icon of the workspace I was in at that time
2. Went to **Add a workspace**
3. Saw that there was one email pending to confirm, so I confirmed it and immediately saw the missing workspace in my home menu together with the rest